# Socket client connect automatically after disconnect

Tags: c#, sockets, connection

I'm using `C#` for socket programming. I've created client/server socket connection over the internet. My problem is that the client disconnect sometimes. I don't know why it happens, because internet connection is robust.

I need to make client to check, which tries to reconnect after it's disconnected from the server.

```
try
{  
     client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

     remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9060);
     client.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("join"), remoteEP);
     data = new byte[20480];

}
catch (Exception kd)
{

}
```

Comment: UDP protocol doesn't use client / server you are perhaps confused with TCP. Further more, there is no connection in UDP protocol as it is a connection less protocol that does not implement acknowledgements for each message sent. Are you sure you have any idea what you are doing?

Comment: yes , my connection works very well , but after a period when client is not transfering with server ... then sccur the error , the server does not send packets to client

Comment: There is no connection in UDP, as your code also doesn't contain no `Connect` call. Please change either code sample or question, or learn first the termology of network communication.

Comment: @user2759163 I stand by what I wrote previously. The code that you supplied has no connection to the problem you are describing or what you claim to try and achieve. Why would you have a disconnection when you are using the loopback interface that doesn't even use the network??? And just to reiterate the point: there is no client server in UDP protocol and no connection!!!

Comment: Check this question's answer and maybe you'll understand the concept of UDP better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344853/c-sharp-udp-multicast-disconnects-after-a-few-seconds?rq=1